# How can I use the "Taxonomy display" view on the Panels taxonomy override page?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to change the weight of Page Manager module to enable the taxonomy term template in Panels. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Page manager module is unable to enable taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term because some other module already has overridden with views_page.
```

I tried to change the weight directly from phpmyadmin but the weight field in page_manager_handler table is empty. I also tried the [util](http://drupal.org/project/util) module but it is not adding the required 'module weight' column in the module listing. Also it clashes with Module Filter module causing drupal to go crazy with a lot of errors.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have a look at `menu_router` table in database. search for `taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term` and see which module associated with it, then change it to yours or delete the row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you don't need to adjust the module weight-- you need to remove the override on the taxonomy term pages.

Are you already overriding the taxonomy term display in Views?  If so, just disable that view and the error should go away.

EDIT: If you still want to use the taxonomy view in Panels, you should edit the view as follows (I do this on one of my sites):

- Open the edit screen for the *Taxonomy display* view.
- Click *page*.
- Where it says *clone page*, click the triangle and select *disable page*.
- Click *Add*.
- Choose *Content pane*.
- Add the content pane.
- Click *Argument input*.
- For the first argument, choose *From panel argument* and *First*.
- For the second argument, choose *From panel argument* and *First*. (identical to the settings for the first)
- Go to your panel and add this content pane instead of the page (it will appear under *View panes*).

Why do you have to do this?  Because otherwise Views and Panels will fight each other over who controls the page.  By using a content pane, you avoid assigning a URL path in Views, allowing Panels to override the path successfully.

Comment: The error does go away on disabling view but I'm using that view to pass content pane to panels. I need to use both to override my taxonomy page.

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how to handle this case.

Comment: I'm doing this because I've created a table to list content teasers but I wanted to add a description on the top of the page before table. View was adding it inside the table so I had to use panels for that. Thanks by the way, your solution worked as always.. :)

Comment: One more thing though. I'm getting this ugly pane title before my table. There is no option in the pane settings for title. How do I remove it?

Comment: I've already set that to none but it still shows up.